# Oracle, performance issue

Tags: oracle, performance, insert

I have a `Insert Into ... SELECT` statement. This statement consists of 3 selects join by `UNION ALL CLAUSE`.

```
Insert into 
(Select... (1)
UNION ALL
Select... (2)
UNION ALL
Select... (3)
)
```

Table, which i'am inserting is in nologging mode, Parallel degree = 8, and using `/*+ APPEND*/` clause.

Selects 1 and 2 are just simple selects over 1 table. I ran this 2 selects in pl/sql block like:

```
Select count(1) into x From
(Select (1) UNION ALL Select... (2))
```

It returned about 1.5 million records in 3 seconds. Then i put these selects into insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
(Select (1) UNION ALL Select... (2))
```

And insert lasted same time as above.

Now, last (3) Select is From 1 table and few joins (including 1 left join). 
When i ran this in `Select Count(1) Into x` It returned 80 000 records in about 3 minutes. 
I expect that insert of 80 000 records would be no longer than time of `select count(1) into`, in the meantime `insert into ... select` has already half an hour of execution time.

- 1.5 milion rec - 3secs
- 80 000 rec - ...

Can Anyone enlight me, whats going on? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: not like that exactly, if you insert just select3 script , how much time take it?

Comment: Your Error is to expect _ select <some_columns>_ running as fast as _select count(1) ..._ 
The Optimizer can often do a _count(1)_ muhc faster than accessing _<some columns>_ 
Please test the _select <some_columns>_ and measure it's time. That#s the baseline for your insert.

Comment: Insert Into ... Select 3 took 37 minutes.

Comment: Martin Berger
It is exactly what im testing.
Select count (1) from ( Select col,col,col... from table))